# gsubbing a string with a pattern containing a newline character in Lua

Tags: string, lua

Does string.gsub recognize the newline character in a string literal? I have a scenario in which I am trying to gsub a portion of a string indicated by a given operator from the start of the operator to the newline like so:

```
local function removeComments(str, operator)
    local new_Sc = (str):gsub(operator..".*\n", "");
    return new_Sc;
end
local source = [[
int hi = 123; //a basic comment
char ok = "abc"; //another comment
]];
source = removeComments(source, "//");
print(source);
```

however in the output I see that it removed the rest of the string literal after the first comment:

```
int hi = 123;
```

I tried using the literal newline character by using `string.char(10)` like so `(str):gsub(operator..".*"..string.char(10), "");` however I still got the same output; it removes the comment and the rest of the string instead of the start of the comment to the newline.

So is there anyway to gsub a string literal for a pattern containing a newline character?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are facing is akin to greedy vs. lazy matching in regular expressions (`.*` vs `.*?`).

In Lua patterns, `X.*\n` means "match X, then match as many as possible characters followed by a newline". `gsub` has no special handling for a newline, hence it will try to continue matching until the *last* newline, subbing as many characters as it can. You want to match as few characters as possible, which is represented by `.-` in Lua patterns.

Also, I am not sure if it is intended or not, but this strategy will not remove the comment from the last line, if it is not (properly) ended by a newline. I am not sure if it can be represented by a single pattern, but this function will remove comments from all lines:

```
local function removeComments(str, operator)
    local new_Sc = str:gsub(operator..".-\n", "\n");
    new_Sc = new_Sc:gsub(operator.."[^\n].*$", "");
    return new_Sc;
end
```